# Spark Dataframe/RDD cannot create new column by counting the contents of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark RDD (or Dataframe - converting to either is not a problem) that has the following columns (example for each structure):

```
res248: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[1004] at map at <console>:246
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, list: array<string>]
```

I want to expand this RDD/DF to have an additional column containing the size of the list array. So the output should be something like this (example):

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, list: array<string>, length_of_list: int]
```

I tried to do an `rdd.map(x=> (x._1,x._2,count(x._2)))` but got an error message:

```
<console>:246: error: overloaded method value count with alternatives:
  (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[Any,Long] <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Tried adding a new column using DF with the function `withColumn("new_column",count($"list"))` or any variation thereof. It still doesn't work. I get an error message complaining about aggregation.

Do you know of a way to achieve this without having to collect the RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is inbuilt function [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#size(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) which returns the length of array or map.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("length_of_list", size($"list"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new column using a simple `UDF` to apply to column `list` as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", Array("x1", "x2", "x3")),
  ("b", Array("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"))
).toDF(
  "id", "list"
)
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, list: array<string>]

val listSize = (l: Seq[String]) => l.size
// listSize: Seq[String] => Int = <function1>

def listSizeUDF = udf(listSize)
// listSizeUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

val df2 = df.withColumn("length_of_list", listSizeUDF($"list"))

df2.show
+---+----------------+--------------+
| id|            list|length_of_list|
+---+----------------+--------------+
|  a|    [x1, x2, x3]|             3|
|  b|[y1, y2, y3, y4]|             4|
+---+----------------+--------------+
```

[UPDATE]

As pointed out by @Ramesh Maharjan, there is a built-in `size` function in Spark which I somehow forgot about.  I'll leave the old answer as a simple use case for using UDF.